# Restoring deleted user, and data associated to him

Tags: user-profile

Someone in my company deleted a user by mistake, they restored it manually.
The problem now is that some workflows are still pointing to the previous ID (92), but the new profile id is 523.

Is it possible to change id from 523 to 92?

Or, Is it possible to change "Author/Created by" from 92 to 523?

Or, Is there any functionality to tell sharepoint 523 is the same profile as the old deleted 92?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Move-SPUser`.

```
$user = Get-SPUser -Identity "i:0#.w|domain\jdoe" -Web http://siteUrl
Move-SPUser -Identity $user -NewAlias "domain\jdoe" -IgnoreSid
```

That will translate the new user's identity into the old identity ('identity' being the SID). This cmdlet works farm-wide.